# cytoscape: on click node ,edge not working properly

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am using cytoscape to generate the below .But when i click exactly on node , its doesnt work but when i click with offset (a bit away from node or edge) then on click event is firing .

In the below picture, when i click exactly on node or edge , click event is not firing but when I click at  red and black dots which are away from node and edge , click event is firing . 
I want it to fire when i click on node (rounded with red pen) . Please help me.

[image]

code:

```
<div id="graphView" class="tabcontent" style="display:block;">
                        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px; text-align: left;">
                            <div id="graphDiv" class="col-sm-9 graphViewStyle"> </div>
                            <div id="toolTipDiv" class="col-sm-3"  style="word-wrap: break-word; min-height:300px;max-height:300px;min-width:200px;overflow-y: auto;border:1px solid black;
                                 border-bottom-left-radius:4px;border-bottom-right-radius:4px;border-top-left-radius:4px;border-top-right-radius:4px;">4678678678678678678ghjghj/n fghfgh</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Cytoscape js code:

```
 var cy = cytoscape({
        //container: document.getElementById('graphView'),
        container: document.getElementById('graphDiv'),

        boxSelectionEnabled: false,
        autounselectify: false,
        zoomingEnabled: false,
        autoungrabify: false,

        style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
                .selector('node')
                .css({
                    'content': 'data(label)'
                })
                .selector('edge')
                .css({
                    'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                    'width': 4,
                    'line-color': '#ccc',
                    'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
                    'curve-style': 'bezier',
                    'content': 'data(label)'
                })


    });
```

Here graphDiv is my div and i am not having any other components in same div.

Comment: You've probably done something you shouldn't like putting other content in the visualisation div.  It's impossible to tell without a full live demo.  You haven't provided any code.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question with code snippets. Thanks

Comment: That's not enough.  You haven't shown all your code, and your problem is in the code you haven't shown.  I suggest you read the tutorials and learn how to get a basic graph working first: http://blog.js.cytoscape.org/tutorials/